# Java 8 Completable Futures allOf different data types

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I have 3 CompletableFutures all 3 returning different data types.

I am looking to create a result object that is a composition of the result returned by all the 3 futures.

So my current working code looks like this:

```
public ClassD getResultClassD() {

    ClassD resultClass = new ClassD();
    CompletableFuture<ClassA> classAFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassA() );
    CompletableFuture<ClassB> classBFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassB() );
    CompletableFuture<ClassC> classCFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassC() );

    CompletableFuture.allOf(classAFuture, classBFuture, classCFuture)
                     .thenAcceptAsync(it -> {
                        ClassA classA = classAFuture.join();
                        if (classA != null) {
                            resultClass.setClassA(classA);
                        }

                        ClassB classB = classBFuture.join();
                        if (classB != null) {
                            resultClass.setClassB(classB);
                        }

                        ClassC classC = classCFuture.join();
                        if (classC != null) {
                            resultClass.setClassC(classC);
                        }

                     });

    return resultClass;
}
```

My questions are:

1. My assumption here is that since I am using `allOf` and `thenAcceptAsync`    this call will be non blocking. Is my understanding right ?
2. Is this the right way to deal with multiple futures returning different result types ?
3. Is it right to construct `ClassD` object within `thenAcceptAsync` ?
4. Is it appropriate to use the `join` or `getNow` method in the thenAcceptAsync lambda ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your attempt is going into the right direction, but not correct. Your method `getResultClassD()` returns an already instantiated object of type `ClassD` on which an arbitrary thread will call modifying methods, without the caller of `getResultClassD()` noticing. This can cause race conditions, if the modifying methods are not thread safe on their own, further, the caller will never know, when the `ClassD` instance is actually ready for use.

A correct solution would be:

```
public CompletableFuture<ClassD> getResultClassD() {

    CompletableFuture<ClassA> classAFuture
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassA() );
    CompletableFuture<ClassB> classBFuture
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassB() );
    CompletableFuture<ClassC> classCFuture
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassC() );

    return CompletableFuture.allOf(classAFuture, classBFuture, classCFuture)
         .thenApplyAsync(dummy -> {
            ClassD resultClass = new ClassD();

            ClassA classA = classAFuture.join();
            if (classA != null) {
                resultClass.setClassA(classA);
            }

            ClassB classB = classBFuture.join();
            if (classB != null) {
                resultClass.setClassB(classB);
            }

            ClassC classC = classCFuture.join();
            if (classC != null) {
                resultClass.setClassC(classC);
            }

            return resultClass;
         });
}
```

Now, the caller of `getResultClassD()` can use the returned `CompletableFuture` to query the progress state or chain dependent actions or use `join()` to retrieve the result, once the operation is completed.

To address the other questions, yes, this operation is asynchronous and the use of `join()` within the lambda expressions is appropriate. `join` was exactly created because `Future.get()`, which is declared to throw checked exceptions, makes the use within these lambda expressions unnecessarily hard.

Note that the `null` tests are only useful, if these `service.getClassX()` can actually return `null`. If one of the service calls fails with an exception, the entire operation (represented by `CompletableFuture<ClassD>`) will complete exceptionally.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. My only followup to your answer is that thenApplyAsync has a return type of CompletableFuture<Void>, how would this work here and how would one invoke this method and consume the result

Comment: No, it’s the return type of `allOf` which is `CompletableFuture<Void>`, that’s why the function passed `thenApplyAsync` receives `Void` as input (the `dummy` parameter above, instead of `dummy ->`, you could also write `(Void dummy) ->`). Then, the function translates the `Void` input (by actually ignoring it) to a `ClassD` result, so the result of `thenApplyAsync` will be `CompletableFuture<ClassD>`.

Comment: @Holger I was going down a similar route to you but I was using Optional.ofNullable in the service calls, so you can have `cCFuture.join().ifPresent(class::SetStuff)`

Comment: @Ash: there’s almost always more than one way to do it…

Comment: @Holger thanks for the explanation about the dummy parameter. Makes sense

Answer (score 6):

I was going down a similar route to what @Holger was doing in his answer, but wrapping the Service Calls in an Optional, which leads to cleaner code in the thenApplyAsync stage

```
CompletableFuture<Optional<ClassA>> classAFuture
    = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Optional.ofNullable(service.getClassA())));

CompletableFuture<Optional<ClassB>> classBFuture
    = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Optional.ofNullable(service.getClassB()));

CompletableFuture<Optional<ClassC>> classCFuture
    = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Optional.ofNullable(service.getClassC()));

return CompletableFuture.allOf(classAFuture, classBFuture, classCFuture)
     .thenApplyAsync(dummy -> {
        ClassD resultClass = new ClassD();

        classAFuture.join().ifPresent(resultClass::setClassA)
        classBFuture.join().ifPresent(resultClass::setClassB)
        classCFuture.join().ifPresent(resultClass::setClassC)

        return resultClass;
     });
```

Comment: yes using optionals is the right way to think of it

Answer (score 3):

I ran into something similar before and created a short demo to show how I solved this issue.

Similar concept to @Holger except I used a function to combine each individual future.

https://github.com/te21wals/CompletableFuturesDemo

Essentially:

```
    public class CombindFunctionImpl implement CombindFunction {
    public ABCData combind (ClassA a, ClassB b, ClassC c) {
        return new ABCData(a, b, c);
   }
}
```

...

```
    public class FutureProvider {
public CompletableFuture<ClassA> retrieveClassA() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ClassA();
    });
}

public CompletableFuture<ClassB> retrieveClassB() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ClassB();
    });
}
public CompletableFuture<ClassC> retrieveClassC() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ClassC();
    });
}
}
```

......

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    CompletableFuture<ClassA> classAfuture = futureProvider.retrieveClassA();
    CompletableFuture<ClassB> classBfuture = futureProvider.retrieveClassB();
    CompletableFuture<ClassC> classCfuture = futureProvider.retrieveClassC();

    System.out.println("starting completable futures ...");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    ABCData ABCData = CompletableFuture.allOf(classAfuture, classBfuture, classCfuture)
            .thenApplyAsync(ignored ->
                    combineFunction.combind(
                            classAfuture.join(),
                            classBfuture.join(),
                            classCfuture.join())
            ).join();

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("completable futures are complete...");
    System.out.println("duration:\t" + Duration.ofNanos(duration).toString());
    System.out.println("result:\t" + ABCData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this if you don't want to declare as many variables is to use thenCombine or thenCombineAsync to chain your futures together.

```
public CompletableFuture<ClassD> getResultClassD()
{
  return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(ClassD::new)
    .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(service::getClassA), (d, a) -> {
      d.setClassA(a);
      return d;
    })
    .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(service::getClassB), (d, b) -> {
      d.setClassB(b);
      return d;
    })
    .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(service::getClassC), (d, c) -> {
      d.setClassC(c);
      return d;
    });
}
```

The getters will still be fired off asynchronously and the results executed in order. It's basically another syntax option to get the same result.

Comment: That's probably a good approach if there are only 2 or 3 futures to combine. However you should probably start from a `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(new ClassD())` as the instantiation is probably not worth running asynchronously. In fact, you could even instantiate it in a `thenApply()` on the first future.