# How to execute an Array of CompletableFuture and combine their results

Tags: java-8, completable-future

I am investigating the use of `Java 8 CompletableFuture`.

The process I am attempting to code is as follows:-

**Extract Keys**

1). Execute a single `CompletableFuture` that returns a `List<String>`

**Extract Data**

2). On completion of step 1). Execute multiple `CompletableFutures` in parallel that accept this `List<String>s` as input. Each `CompletableFuture` executed in step 2). returns a unique list of Value Objects.

**Combine Data**

3). Once all `CompletableFutures` executed in step 2). have completed I wish to combine the individual lists of Value Objects and complete the process.

The code I have working can only cope with two CompletableFutures executing during Step 2). as follows:-

```
final CompletableFuture<List<String>> extractor = get("https://example.com//source/url");

final CompletableFuture<List<Documentable>> valueObjectList1 = extractor.thenApplyAsync(s -> callTypeADocumentable(s));
final CompletableFuture<List<Documentable>> valueObjectList2 = extractor.thenApplyAsync(s -> callTypeBCDocumentable(s));

valueObjectList1.thenCombineAsync(valueObjectList2, (c, e) -> consumeBothDocumentable(c, e)).thenAccept(x -> finish(x));
```

My desired solution is to achieve this:-

```
final CompletableFuture<List<String>> extractor = get("https://example.com//source/url");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final CompletableFuture<List<Documentable>>[] completableFutures = new CompletableFuture[ENDPOINT.values().length];

int index = 0;

for (ENDPOINT endpoint : ENDPOINT.values()) {

    final CompletableFuture<List<Documentable>> valueObjectList = extractor.thenApplyAsync(s -> endpoint.contactEndpoit(s));

        completableFutures[index++] = valueObjectList;

    }

completableFutures[0].allOf(completableFutures[1], completableFutures[2], ...);
```

How can I combine multiple `CompletableFutures` (e.g. More than two) in the same manner as I did for exactly two `CompletableFutures`

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42489496/2711488) helps…

Comment: @Holger nice work. That Q&A helped. I feel Like I am beginning to understand CompletableFutures :).