# How to use two independent services and use the result of those service as Input of another service using ComputableFuture concept?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I am trying to use and understand Java8 CompletableFuture concept. Please help me to under if there is a way I can implement by below scenario.

**Scenario Description:**
I have a **Car repository** and a **user repository**.

I have individual service like: **getUserData (returns List)** and **getCarData (returns List)** to fetch me the values.

Now I have created another **repository called: CarBooking** and it has a service called createNewBooking, which should **accept List and List as input**.

Is there any way that I can create a chained method using CompletableFuture which can combine these services/tasks to be triggered.

Like CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::getUserData).....

I am not able to understand how can I join another service and use first and second value to third service as BiConsumer.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490017/4417924

Comment: Thanks Jason. It does answer my question. I have applied the flow mentioned in that and it did work.